# Is it possible to wait all the threads to finish before starting next iteration in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to wait all the threads till each thread finishes its task in a thread group and start new iteration with all threads once again at same time.

i.e. for every iteration I want to make sure all the threads completed in last iteration.

Please provide your input for my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer). Place it as `a child of the last Sampler` in the script, so all threads will wait for other threads to reach the last step.

Set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to `0`, Timer will wait for the `number of threads` configured in `current Thread Group`.

**Warning:** This will result in sudden load (Spike) to the server as all threads starts the last step at the same time.

From JMeter Docs:

> Note that timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in
>   which they are found; if there are several timers in the same scope,
>   all the timers will be processed before each sampler.  Timers are only
>   processed in conjunction with a sampler. A timer which is not in the
>   same scope as a sampler will not be processed at all.
>
> To apply a  timer to a single sampler, add the timer as a child element of the
>   sampler. The timer will be applied before the sampler is executed. To
>   apply a timer after a sampler, either add it to the next sampler, or
>   add it as the child of a Test Action Sampler.

So, try to keep  Synchronizing Timer as a child of [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler **Or** Add a `Debug Sampler` and add  `Synchronizing Timer` to it as a child, to avoid the unwanted spike as mentioned in **Warning**.

References:

1. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer
2. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer

Comment: Thank you @Naveen. It is very useful. I will try this.